# Remove first and last three character of a word with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users in a text file who's names are in the following format: **xn-tsai-01.**

How do I script to remove the **xn- KEEP THIS -01** so the output is like: **tsai**

I know how to do this in bash but not too familiar with powershell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it using regex:

```
'xn-tsai-01' -replace '.*?-(.*)-.*','$1'
```

Example with a list:

```
(Get-Content list.txt) -Replace '.*?-(.*)-.*','$1'
```

Comment: but the users are located in a textile?

Comment: @NebelzCheez Well have you tried _anything_ to import that text file `Get-Content` would be what you should use to start?

Comment: You should make the first `.*`  not greedy in case the username has dashes. Beyond that this is the approach I would have taken.

Comment: Added an example with Get-Content; @Matt Good call on the 'not greedy' with the regex!

Comment: Thanks guys! & yes Matt I did try gc. I was doing gc .\list.txt -Replace '.*?-(.*)-.*','$1'  - didn't notice the parenthesis

Comment: @NebelzCheez Glad you got what you needed. Next time add what you have tried to the question and it can save everyone sometime. Without that it just sounds like you are putting no effort into it.

Comment: Will do Matt, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Why not use Substring method.  If you will always trim the first three characters, you can do the following assuming the variable is a string type.

```
$string = xn-tsai-01
$string.Substring(3)
```

Comment: Wow! Much better then eldritch arcanum of regexps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .NET string method `IndexOf("-")` to find the first, and `LastIndexOf("-")` to find the last occurrence of "-" within the string.

Use these indexes with `Substring()` to remove the unnecessary parts:

```
function Clean-Username {
    param($Name)
    $FirstDash = $Name.IndexOf("-") + 1
    $LastDash  = $Name.LastIndexOf("-")
    return $Name.Substring( $f, $l - $f )
}

PS C:\> Clean-UserName -Name "xn-tsai-01"
tsai
```

Comment: How do I use this if the list of users are located in a text file?

Comment: Spend a little time researching this.
`$names = GC list.txt; foreach($name in $names){clean-username -name $name}`
You can even put this all into one script.

Answer (score 2):

Boe's example is probably going to be the most efficient.

Another way is to use the `split()` method if they're in a uniform format.

```
Get-Content .\list.txt | % { ($_.Split('-'))[1] }
```

% is an alias for `ForEach`